# How to assign CSV file without using ${__threadNum} in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, functional, csv-file, http

I'm facing problem with assigning the CSV file on the basis of loop count, not on the basis of thread count.

For example -> `address1.csv, address2.csv......addressn.csv`

So it is very easy to do the same using `${__threadNum}` function (already tried and know about this but our requirement deals with loop count ) But i want do it on basis of loop Count like 1,2 .....n

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) just the same way you're using `__threadNum()` function. The `__counter()` function generates an incremented number each time it's being called.
2. Another option is going for [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element, if you put it inside your loop you will be able to refer incremented value by reference name. See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) for more details.
3. Also be aware of [__iterationNum() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup), it returns current [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) loop number. If this is something you're looking for - you can install this function via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager - Custom JMeter Functions]

Comment: Hi....above answer quite related my question so in that 3rd one i am looking for that. so thing is in my csv data set config path is D:\datas\latandlong\IndiaAddress\address${__iterationNum}.csv  
 mentioned in the File Name path but it is not taking... how do that one. any suggestion you have please tell me

Comment: __iterationNum() How to use it with loop count please tell me with simple example